# Mark values that deviate too much from average for given ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I mark a cell if its value deviates too much from all others with the same ID?

In the following example I have point IDs with values assigned.

```
[Point ID][Number]
 1000      5.321
 1001      3.245 // <----- mark cell or put some indication in next column
 1002      2.647
 1002      2.643
 1001      3.286 // <----- mark cell or put some indication in next column
 1000      5.320
```

I am currently calculating the average for each ID with `SUM.IF`and `COUNT.IF`. But if there is too much difference between a value and the average, I would like to know without comparing each one by hand. Maybe it's possible with an `INDEX` lookup, but I'm not sure how to compare them.

So, how can I lookup these values on the left column and note when the values differentiate too much from the average?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: How can I find differences in a lookup. I have no clue and cannot find something suitable online.

Comment: What would you consider too much deviation?

Comment: @ScottCraner wouldn't `X` be enough to answer the question? A variable number would be nice, otherwise `0,02` in the case of my example.

Comment: You would have to set up another column that calculates the standard deviation or some other form of figuring out if the cell is "too far" away from the other numbers and then use that column as your reference for the sumif

Comment: Are there more than two for each id? If so what do you want to use as the base line, the avarage, the one before it ...?

Comment: @ScottCraner Good question. Yes there can ben more then a dozen of each ID but most often it will be just 2. If one of the ID's is deviating too much it is most probably an incorrect measurement and I need to be aware it drives the average of the correct ones off. So the baseline could be the first number it finds so if there is too much deviation I can investigate manually and I know where to look between hundreds of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a conditional formatting rule to get what you've described. Just select the values in your table you'd like to format (B1:B6 in my example using your sample data) and click `Conditional Formatting > New Rule...` in the Home ribbon.

From there, choose `Use a formula to choose which cells to format`, and enter the formula below, of course adjusted to match the size and location of your actual data.

```
=ABS(SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,$A1)-$B1)>0.01
```

The last number (0.01) is the threshold deviation for highlighting a cell. Set this to whatever you like.

Finally, set how you'd like the cells to be formatted.

[image]

Comment: could you use `=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$6,$A1,$B$1:$B$6) - $B1>0.01`, just a little less typing :)

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, but with the `ABS` function included too.